# Best way to handle release versions across multiple servers using git/plesk

Tags: git, webserver, git-branch, plesk, release-management

I have a library of code that I want to use across several websites. I want to be able to control which release each site is using (in the case that upgrades need making to the database/config files of the site).

What would be the recommended way of managing this, bearing in mind each website will be managed with Plesk which gives me limited control - largely just changing the active branch?

My best guess is that I have each "release" as a separate branch, so at certain points in the development I create a branch from master as a snapshot of the code, then control which branch is active on the site via Plesk by selecting that branch - leaving master as the current "latest" version.

Is there a better way of handling releases (in vanilla git, nothing github/gitlab/etc specific) that I haven't touched on?

I'm also wanting to be able to push to the webserver, rather than FTPing up a snapshot of a branch - just because it fits in with my current workflow, but if that's the roadblock I could change.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

To clarify, the code libraries sit above the httpdocs folder in each vhost, so 1 copy per website. Each site may require a different version of the code, think similar to themes and wordpress, the theme (main site code) may require changes before the wordpress (library) can be updated.

I think the limiting factor will be how much control Plesk will allow and right now that's limited to selecting a directory and a branch.

Comment: What about using submodule ?

Comment: How are the websites referencing the shared code? Is the shared code built separately and versioned, in such a way that each site can run a different version of the shared code?

Comment: I've updated the post with some more information.

I'll read up on submodules tonight.

The shared code is all PHP so doesn't need "building" per se, but yes, it's versioned so each site can run it at different versions (and as the main code of the site is updated I can move to a newer version).